# Javascript: How to retrieve the number of decimals of a *string* number?

Tags: javascript, string, numbers, decimal

I have a set of string numbers having decimals, for example: `23.456`, `9.450`, `123.01`... I need to retrieve the number of decimals for each number, knowing that they have at least 1 decimal.

In other words, the `retr_dec()` method should return the following:

```
retr_dec("23.456") -> 3
retr_dec("9.450")  -> 3
retr_dec("123.01") -> 2
```

Trailing zeros do count as a decimal in this case, unlike in this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9539513/is-there-a-reliable-way-in-javascript-to-obtain-the-number-of-decimal-places-of).

Is there an easy/delivered method to achieve this in Javascript or should I compute the decimal point position and compute the difference with the string length? Thanks

Answer (score 117, accepted):

```
function decimalPlaces(num) {
  var match = (''+num).match(/(?:\.(\d+))?(?:[eE]([+-]?\d+))?$/);
  if (!match) { return 0; }
  return Math.max(
       0,
       // Number of digits right of decimal point.
       (match[1] ? match[1].length : 0)
       // Adjust for scientific notation.
       - (match[2] ? +match[2] : 0));
}
```

The extra complexity is to handle scientific notation so

> ```
> decimalPlaces('.05')
> 2
> decimalPlaces('.5')
> 1
> decimalPlaces('1')
> 0
> decimalPlaces('25e-100')
> 100
> decimalPlaces('2.5e-99')
> 100
> decimalPlaces('.5e1')
> 0
> decimalPlaces('.25e1')
> 1
> ```

Comment: Note that the OP has already stated that it is not a number, but a string with a number inside.

Comment: @Phrogz, I don't think that affects the validity of my answer, except that maybe I shouldn't count 0's on the end of the \.(\d+)

Comment: It doesn't, I just wanted to point out that the `''+` was unnecessary in this case.

Comment: 1.00 returns 0 :(, instead of 2

Comment: @arod, `decimalPlaces("1.00") === 2` but `decimalPlaces(1.00) === 0` because `("" + 1.00) === "1"`.  The function operates on string representations of numbers, not primitive numeric values because primitive numeric values aren't inherently decimal -- [IEEE 854 didn't make it into EcmaScript 5](http://intertwingly.net/blog/2008/07/11/Decimal-in-ECMAScript).

Comment: I wish I had more upvotes to give this lovely function.

Comment: Isn't this a dupe of [this other question you've answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9539513/is-there-a-reliable-way-in-javascript-to-obtain-the-number-of-decimal-places-of)?

Comment: @DanDascalescu, seems like it.  I'm always surprised when I find that I disagree with myself.

Answer (score 59):

```
function retr_dec(num) {
  return (num.split('.')[1] || []).length;
}
```

Comment: @Deleteman Thankfully OP specified `knowing that they have at least 1 decimal`

Comment: This won't work for really small numbers that are printed in exponential notation.

Comment: Works great. Comments saying doesn't work when no decimal in string refer to this answer before the edit.

Comment: If the number is really small like 0.00000001, the num.toString() will return something like 1e-7 and this code will not work.

Comment: This also doesn't work for some "international" numbers where the numbers may be written like so `3.000,00`

Answer (score 10):

```
function retr_dec(numStr) {
    var pieces = numStr.split(".");
    return pieces[1].length;
}
```

Comment: Or even simplier: numStr.split(".")[1].length;

Comment: worth pointing out that if your number is not a string this wont work.  To get it working `var pieces = numStr.toString().split(".");`

Comment: This case will throw an error if there is no decimal, e.g: `123`.

Answer (score 5):

Since there is not already a regex-based answer:

```
/\d*$/.exec(strNum)[0].length
```

*Note that this "fails" for integers, but per the problem specification they will never occur.*

Comment: @LarryBattle I appreciate your comment and thoroughness, but the question clearly states, _"knowing that they have at least 1 decimal"_. If you down voted my correct answer for this reason, I ask you to reconsider your vote.

Answer (score 3):

You could get the length of the decimal part of your number this way:

```
var value = 192.123123;
stringValue = value.toString();
length = stringValue.split('.')[1].length;
```

It makes the number a string, splits the string in two (at the decimal point) and returns the length of the second element of the array returned by the split operation and stores it in the 'length' variable.

Comment: OP stated that the numbers are already strings. Your answer does not provide anything new that hasn't already been suggested by Jack and Daniel Bidulock

Comment: This is by far the most straightforward answer to OP's question. OP does not ask for other notations to be taken into account (octal? hex?)

Comment: Look out for the scientific representation of the number before the decimals. It will kick in when the numbers length is 20 and above

Answer (score 2):

Try using `String.prototype.match()` with `RegExp` `/\..*/` , return `.length` of matched string `-1`

```js
function retr_decs(args) {
  return /\./.test(args) && args.match(/\..*/)[0].length - 1 || "no decimal found"
}

console.log(
  retr_decs("23.456") // 3
  , retr_decs("9.450") // 3
  , retr_decs("123.01") // 2
  , retr_decs("123") // "no decimal found"
)
```

Comment: FYI, this does not count trailing 0s. `retr_decs("9.00") // "no decimal found"`

Comment: @Gaʀʀʏ Returns `2` here https://jsfiddle.net/24rqjr83/. Can you reproduce `"no decimal found"` being returned at jsfiddle?

Comment: This is very strange. When I was testing it yesterday I was not having trailing zeros counted. I verified your jsfiddle and locally as well that the function is handling them. Weird. You have my upvote.

Answer (score 2):

I had to deal with very small numbers so I created a version that can handle numbers like 1e-7.

```js
Number.prototype.getPrecision = function() {
  var v = this.valueOf();
  if (Math.floor(v) === v) return 0;
  var str = this.toString();
  var ep = str.split("e-");
  if (ep.length > 1) {
    var np = Number(ep[0]);
    return np.getPrecision() + Number(ep[1]);
  }
  var dp = str.split(".");
  if (dp.length > 1) {
    return dp[1].length;
  }
  return 0;
}
document.write("NaN => " + Number("NaN").getPrecision() + "<br>");
document.write("void => " + Number("").getPrecision() + "<br>");
document.write("12.1234 => " + Number("12.1234").getPrecision() + "<br>");
document.write("1212 => " + Number("1212").getPrecision() + "<br>");
document.write("0.0000001 => " + Number("0.0000001").getPrecision() + "<br>");
document.write("1.12e-23 => " + Number("1.12e-23").getPrecision() + "<br>");
document.write("1.12e8 => " + Number("1.12e8").getPrecision() + "<br>");
```

Answer (score 1):

A slight modification of the currently accepted answer, this adds to the `Number` prototype, thereby allowing all number variables to execute this method:

```js
if (!Number.prototype.getDecimals) {
    Number.prototype.getDecimals = function() {
        var num = this,
            match = ('' + num).match(/(?:\.(\d+))?(?:[eE]([+-]?\d+))?$/);
        if (!match)
            return 0;
        return Math.max(0, (match[1] ? match[1].length : 0) - (match[2] ? +match[2] : 0));
    }
}
```

It can be used like so:

```js
// Get a number's decimals.
var number = 1.235256;
console.debug(number + " has " + number.getDecimals() + " decimal places.");

// Get a number string's decimals.
var number = "634.2384023";
console.debug(number + " has " + parseFloat(number).getDecimals() + " decimal places.");
```

Utilizing our existing code, the second case could also be easily added to the `String` prototype like so:

```js
if (!String.prototype.getDecimals) {
    String.prototype.getDecimals = function() {
        return parseFloat(this).getDecimals();
    }
}
```

Use this like:

```js
console.debug("45.2342".getDecimals());
```

Answer (score 1):

A bit of a hybrid of two others on here but this worked for me. Outside cases in my code weren't handled by others here. However, I had removed the scientific decimal place counter. Which I would have loved at uni!

```
numberOfDecimalPlaces: function (number) {
    var match = ('' + number).match(/(?:\.(\d+))?(?:[eE]([+-]?\d+))?$/);
    if (!match || match[0] == 0) {
        return 0;
    }
     return match[0].length;
}
```

Comment: If you remove the scientific decimal place counter, you can simplify your regex: /(?:\.(\d+))?$/

Plus you use match[0] instead of match[1].

Answer (score 0):

Based on Liam Middleton's answer, here's what I did (without scientific notation):

```js
numberOfDecimalPlaces = (number) => {
            let match = (number + "").match(/(?:\.(\d+))?$/);
            if (!match || !match[1]) {
                return 0;
            }

            return match[1].length;
        };
        
alert(numberOfDecimalPlaces(42.21));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function decimalPlaces(n) {
  if (n === NaN || n === Infinity)
    return 0;
  n = ('' + n).split('.');
  if (n.length == 1) {
    if (Boolean(n[0].match(/e/g)))
      return ~~(n[0].split('e-'))[1];
    return 0;

  }
  n = n[1].split('e-');
  return n[0].length + ~~n[1];

}
```

Comment: This gonna handle every condition rather be scientific or not

Comment: Casting to string and checking for scientific notation is not really the scope of this question (which is almost 6 years old).

Answer (score 0):

if it's guaranteed to have digits below the radix, already in string format, no trailing non-digit bytes,  and no chance of scientific notations, then why not just

> ```
>   # 1-based indices
>
>   length( decstr ) - index( decstr , "." )
> ```