# Simplest way of getting the number of decimals in a number in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, numbers, mootools, decimal-point

Is there a better way of figuring out the number of decimals on a number than in my example?

```
var nbr = 37.435.45;
var decimals = (nbr!=Math.floor(nbr))?(nbr.toString()).split('.')[1].length:0;
```

By better I mean faster to execute and/or using a native JavaScript function, ie. something like nbr.getDecimals().

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

After modifying series0ne answer, the fastest way I could manage is:

```
var val = 37.435345;
var countDecimals = function(value) {
    if (Math.floor(value) !== value)
        return value.toString().split(".")[1].length || 0;
    return 0;
}
countDecimals(val);
```

Speed test: http://jsperf.com/checkdecimals

Comment: Have a look at this very thorough answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10454518/javascript-how-to-retrieve-the-number-of-decimals-of-a-string-number

Comment: Thank you but the asker specified that there has to be a decimal in the numbers whereas I do not. +1 for the interesting link

Comment: @PhilippeTrépanier, consider what it more important in the grand scheme of things. How fast the JavaScript executes (the different between my answer and Pete D's is minimal), and the speed it downloads to the client? Since Pete D's answer is a few bytes shorter, Personally I'd be in a predicament on which one to choose.

Comment: @series0ne, I am in a predicament but since you gave an explanation on the working of your code, you gave the prototypal way of doing it and your answer was faster than his, I gave the correct answer to you.

Comment: @PhilippeTrépanier, Fair enough, I can't argue with that! :-) thanks.

Answer (score 156, accepted):

```
Number.prototype.countDecimals = function () {
    if(Math.floor(this.valueOf()) === this.valueOf()) return 0;
    return this.toString().split(".")[1].length || 0; 
}
```

When bound to the prototype, this allows you to get the decimal count (`countDecimals();`) directly from a number variable.

E.G.

```
var x = 23.453453453;
x.countDecimals(); // 9
```

It works by converting the number to a string, splitting at the **.** and returning the last part of the array, or 0 if the last part of the array is undefined (which will occur if there was no decimal point).

If you do not want to bind this to the prototype, you can just use this:

```
var countDecimals = function (value) {
    if(Math.floor(value) === value) return 0;
    return value.toString().split(".")[1].length || 0; 
}
```

---

EDIT by Black:

I have fixed the method, to also make it work with smaller numbers like `0.000000001`

```js
Number.prototype.countDecimals = function () {

    if (Math.floor(this.valueOf()) === this.valueOf()) return 0;

    var str = this.toString();
    if (str.indexOf(".") !== -1 && str.indexOf("-") !== -1) {
        return str.split("-")[1] || 0;
    } else if (str.indexOf(".") !== -1) {
        return str.split(".")[1].length || 0;
    }
    return str.split("-")[1] || 0;
}


var x = 23.453453453;
console.log(x.countDecimals()); // 9

var x = 0.0000000001;
console.log(x.countDecimals()); // 10

var x = 0.000000000000270;
console.log(x.countDecimals()); // 13

var x = 101;  // Integer number
console.log(x.countDecimals()); // 0
```

Comment: Thank you, that is exactly what I need! I'll accept as soon as my cooldown is gone...

Comment: This will produce an error for integer number: http://jsfiddle.net/3bQqV/ But maybe it is not a problem for OP

Comment: @roasted, well spotted, I'll work on that

Comment: using modulo as Pete D's answer would be faster, anyway +1

Comment: following my last comment, no, it is faster to use floor() method

Comment: @Math.floor is probably faster because it's a [native code] function, meaning it's already compiled into the JS runtime, whereas the modulo equivalent needs to be interpreted/JIT'ed.

Comment: What if I need to know the decimals of a number entered inside an input? I'm trying this: `console.log($('#myinput').val().countDecimals());` but the result is: **Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function**

Comment: for number 23.00 it shows count as 0

Comment: Also produces error with very small decimal amounts. (e.g 0.000000001) http://jsfiddle.net/yh2Lurf5/

Comment: Some countries use comma as decimal separator, not a period. I've used this quick'n'dirty detection trick in the past to deal with that:
`var isComma = Boolean(parseFloat(1 / 2).toString().indexOf(",") !== -1);`
your last line would become:
`return value.toString().split((isComma ? "," : "."))[1].length || 0;`

Comment: this wont work for when decimal value is zero. let say 10.0 it returns 0 since we are doing Math.floor(value) is equal to value.
only 

return this.toString().split(".")[1].length || 0;

 is enough for the solution

Comment: I rather use it as a function, then you get used to having this in Number and when you go to another project you don't have it. Composition is more flexible.

Comment: Now with optional chaining beeing available, this might make the function safer (eg. NaN) ```value.toString().split(".")[1]?.length || 0;``` https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optionale_Verkettung

Comment: @AndreasRiedmüller `null`, `undefined` and `NaN` will evaluate to `0` because of the `|| 0`, but good point all the same.

Comment: This is broken for some numbers, 0.0000001 for example.

Comment: Also this will produce error for exponential numbers like `8e-7`

Comment: @Balage `Number.prototype.toString()` will never return a string containing a comma no matter what the user's locale is.

Comment: @Black: this does not work for negative numbers...?

Comment: @xavier I replaced `var str = this.toString();` with `var str = Math.abs(this).toString();` to handle negative numbers.

Comment: @Black the 3rd test case is incorrect. The value "0.000000000000270" has 14 decimals, not 13.

This is because "0.000000000000270" is represented in JS as "2.7e-13", where "2.7" is the significand. The current solution does not take into account the decimal places within the significand itself, which is why the 3rd test case is off by 1.

Comment: @TJMarkham, oh ok, feel free to fix it

Comment: @Black I ended up fixing it locally in the code I was writing. I tried to update this answer but got a notification that the review queue was full. If I get some free time I'll try again.

Answer (score 50):

Adding to series0ne answer if you want to have the code not throw an error for an integer number and get a result of 0 when there are no decimals use this:

```
var countDecimals = function (value) { 
    if ((value % 1) != 0) 
        return value.toString().split(".")[1].length;  
    return 0;
};
```

Comment: maybe faster like it: `var countDecimals = function (value) { 
    return value % 1?value.toString().split(".")[1].length:0;    
};`

Comment: @OP you should test answers in jsperf to see which seems the best one

Comment: As JavaScript is a size critical language, you could omit the else statement. ie.. if(true) return x; return 0; ... basically if it does not return the amount of decimals, just return 0;

Comment: yeap it would be faster using ternary but I think it's easier to read and understand the concept. OP can change that concept to a more faster way.

Comment: @roasted did that, series0ne's the fastest http://jsperf.com/checkdecimals

Comment: @PhilippeTrépanier  thank you, interresting result!

Comment: Actually now that series0ne edited my code by removing the else statement its faster than his original. Good job series0ne +1 EDIT: removed false jsperf. My bad.

Comment: @PeteD your jsperf was wrong, here is the correct one: http://jsperf.com/checkdecimals/4

Answer (score 2):

Regex are very very not efficient in calculations, they are mean if you can go another way. So I would avoid them :)

Things like "Number % 1" return the rounded decimal value (2.3 % 1 = 0.2999999999999998), and in a general way I would advice you to use strings as early as possible, since approximations with real numbers can change the number of decimals.

So yours is fine, but I'll look a way to optimize it.

Edit:

```
function CountDecimalDigits(number)
{
  var char_array = number.toString().split(""); // split every single char
  var not_decimal = char_array.lastIndexOf(".");
  return (not_decimal<0)?0:char_array.length - not_decimal;
}
```

Comment: You have an off by one error. `char_array.length - not_decimal` should be `char_array.length - not_decimal - 1`

Comment: it also gives an incorrect result if you give it a whole number