# Number.prototype.function not working on result of jQuery(..).val()

Tags: javascript, jquery, numbers, prototype

I took this piece of code from another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17369098/simplest-way-of-getting-the-number-of-decimals-in-a-number-in-javascript).

```
Number.prototype.countDecimals = function () {
    if(Math.floor(this.valueOf()) === this.valueOf()) return 0;
    return this.toString().split(".")[1].length || 0; 
}

var x = 23.453453453;
x.countDecimals(); //returns 9 as expected
```

Basically, it returns the amount of decimal places in a given number. The problem is that I need to get that value from a number that is inside an input:

```
console.log($('#myinput').val().countDecimals());
```

...but that action returns: **Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function**

How can I integrate the previous code to work with input values (with jQuery)? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're defining the `countDecimals` function in the prototype of `Number` objects, so it can only be called on objects of type `Number`. I haven't tested this, but you can use `Number($('#myinput').val()).countDecimals()` instead.

Comment: What would be the difference between using **Number** and **parseFloat**? (both worked fine)

Comment: `countDecimals` would work on any Number *or* number value; JavaScript promotes the primitive type to the corresponding object type as needed. (This is why `1.23.toFixed(1)` works, for instance.)

Comment: @andufo `parseFloat()` makes this into a float number. `Number()` makes it into a number. Both make it a number in general.

Answer (score 2):

This is because `.val()` actually returns an object: `Object [value]`. Just do `parseFloat` on it:

```
console.log( parseFloat( $('#myinput').val() ).countDecimals() );
```

Comment: that actually throws this error: **TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined**

Comment: @andufo Did you define `value`? Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/5p8L84ot/

Comment: perfect! it actually worked, i had an error while testing your solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

it'll give the desired result,

```
 <html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<input type ="text" id="inpVal">
<input type ="button" id="inpBtn" value="click!!!!">
<script>
Number.prototype.countDecimals = function () {
    if(Math.floor(this.valueOf()) === this.valueOf()) return 0;
    return this.toString().split(".")[1].length || 0; 
}

$("#inpBtn").click(function(){
    var x = parseFloat($("#inpVal").val()).countDecimals();
    alert(x);
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: yes, but it just won't work if I try to execute `$('#myinput').val().countDecimals()` and that's what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: my bad , got the question wrong. Have corrected it.