# Add zero only when empty precision in javascript

Tags: jquery, numbers, tofixed

I have a situation here in javascript

```
**Value**       **Expected**  **toFixed(2)**
var a = 0.0273 |  0.0273     |  0.03(X)
var b = 0.8    |  0.80       |  0.80
var b = 53.7   | 53.70       | 53.70
```

When four digits come after the decimal point, leave it as it is, but if a single digit comes, a zero should be appended.

`toFixed()` method didn't help me much.

Comment: this is your answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/15266797/1570534

Comment: you can split the number on the point : `var array=a.toString().split(".")` and then you can find if you need  `toFixed()` or not :  `if(array[1].length<2){
a.toFixed(2);
 } // no else is needed`

Answer (score 0):

First you check the amount of decimals with:

```
var countDecimals = function (value) { 
    if ((value % 1) != 0) 
        return value.toString().split(".")[1].length;  
    return 0;
};
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/17369384/1870760

Then you check if it's 4 or not and parse it with `toFixed`:

```
var a = 0.0273;

    var countDecimals = function (value) { 
        if ((value % 1) != 0) 
            return value.toString().split(".")[1].length;  
        return 0;
    };

if(countDecimals(a) < 4)
  a = (Math.round(a * 100) / 100).toFixed(2);

alert(a)
```

Comment: thanks for the response. Don't we have any other option without the help of user defined methods?

Comment: To count decimals, no.