# Add decimal place to JQuery number count up

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi all I have the following code to count up a number from a figure in my database. If I set the number to count up as a decimal for example 0.2 it breaks the script. I want it to instead count up to one decimal place eg if it is 0.2 then every second it will count up 0.2 -> 0.4 -> 0.6 etc. Obviously if this figure is just say 3 it should still count up 3 -> 6 -> 9 etc.

Cannot work out how to do this! Please help!

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    timer = setInterval("countUP()", 1000);
  });

  var counter = 0;
  var timer;

  function countUP() {
    var go = document.getElementsByClassName("standard");
    for (var i = 0; i < go.length; i++) {
      speed = parseInt(go[i].getAttribute('data-speed'));
      go[i].setAttribute('data-counter', +go[i].getAttribute('data-counter') + speed);
      go[i].innerHTML = numberWithCommas(go[i].getAttribute('data-counter'));
      }
    }
    function numberWithCommas(x) {
x = x.toString();
var pattern = /(-?\d+)(\d{3})/;
while (pattern.test(x))
    x = x.replace(pattern, "$1,$2");
return x;}
</script>
```

I then have this in my main html:

```
<div class="<?php echo $row["countuptype"]; ?>" data-speed="<?php echo $row["countupspeed"]; ?>">0</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this one:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    timer = setInterval("countUP()", 1000);
});

var counter = 0;
var timer;

function countUP() {
    var go = document.getElementsByClassName("standard");
    for (var i = 0; i < go.length; i++) {
        speed = parseFloat(go[i].getAttribute('data-speed'));
        go[i].setAttribute('data-counter', +go[i].getAttribute('data-counter') + speed);
        go[i].innerHTML = numberWithCommas(parseFloat(go[i].getAttribute('data-counter')).toFixed(speed.countDecimals()));
    }
}
function numberWithCommas(x) {
    x = x.toString();
    var pattern = /(-?\d+)(\d{3})/;
    while (pattern.test(x))
    x = x.replace(pattern, "$1,$2");
    return x;
}

Number.prototype.countDecimals = function () {
    if(Math.floor(this.valueOf()) === this.valueOf()) return 0;
    return this.toString().split(".")[1].length || 0; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="standard" data-speed="0.2">0</div>
```

The speed should do `parseFloat` instead of `parseInt` to accept float values as speed.

And then you could get some strange numbers like 0.899999999 due to the [float precision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11695618/dealing-with-float-precision-in-javascript). To prevent from this I've used the toFloat passing [the precision of the speed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17369098/simplest-way-of-getting-the-number-of-decimals-in-a-number-in-javascript) just before printing the value.

And the rest is just what you had.