# Add .00 (toFixed) only if number has less than two decimal places

Tags: javascript, number-formatting

I need to add zeroes, so that each number has at least two decimals, but without rounding.  So for example:

```
5      --> 5.00
5.1    --> 5.10
5.11   --> 5.11 (no change)
5.111  --> 5.111 (no change)
5.1111 -->  5.1111  (no change)
```

My function is missing an IF to check for less than two decimal places:

```
function addZeroes( num ) {
   var num = Number(num);
   if ( //idk ) {
      num = num.toFixed(2);
   }
   return num;
}
```

Thanks!

Posting an alternative answer, in addition to the two below.  (Keep in mind that I'm no expert and this is just for text inputs, not for parsing complex values like colors that could have floating point issues, etc.)

```
function addZeroes( value ) {
    //set everything to at least two decimals; removs 3+ zero decimasl, keep non-zero decimals
    var new_value = value*1; //removes trailing zeros
    new_value = new_value+''; //casts it to string

    pos = new_value.indexOf('.');
    if (pos==-1) new_value = new_value + '.00';
    else {
        var integer = new_value.substring(0,pos);
        var decimals = new_value.substring(pos+1);
        while(decimals.length<2) decimals=decimals+'0';
        new_value = integer+'.'+decimals;
    }
    return new_value;
}
```

[This is not a duplicate question.  The question you linked assumes "knowing that they have at least 1 decimal."  Decimal points cannot be assumed in text inputs, and this was making errors.]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10454518/javascript-how-to-retrieve-the-number-of-decimals-of-a-string-number

Comment: Or just goodle "javascript count digits after decimal"

Comment: So your function will sometimes return string and sometimes number? That's weird

Comment: It seemed that numbers entered into input type=text were understood as strings and that I should convert them to number.

Comment: Please don't close my question.  I read the answer you linked before I posted.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

#### TL;DR:

```js
num.toLocaleString("en", { minimumFractionDigits: 2 })
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fergmux/f0weL8pt/)

#### Other options:

If you are using optional chaining you can do it in one line like so:

```js
const addZeroes = num => Number(num).toFixed(Math.max(num.split('.')[1]?.length, 2) || 2)
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fergmux/0w15jf34/35/)

Without optional chaining you can do it like this:

```js
function addZeroes(num) {
  const dec = num.split('.')[1]
  const len = dec && dec.length > 2 ? dec.length : 2
  return Number(num).toFixed(len)
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fergmux/0w15jf34/34/)

Verbose method/explanation:

```js
function addZeroes(num) {        
  var value = Number(num); // Convert input string to a number

  var parts = num.split("."); // Split the input string into two arrays

  // If there is no decimal point or not enough significant figures
  if(parts.length == 1 || parts[1].length < 3) { 
    value = value.toFixed(2); // Set the number to two decimal places
  }

  return value; // Return the value
}

// If you require the number as a string simply cast back as so
var num = String(value);
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jhKuk/159/)

Comment: You saved my time

Comment: @Frugras num return as string, is possible to return a number like 1.00

Comment: you can do like this also   function(num){ return Number(num).toFixed(2) }

Comment: @cale_b Good point, I've added some comments to help explain, as well as neatening up the code somewhat. In regards to your reply to Elankeeran, the fiddle seems to produce the correct results when returning as a number, so no string conversion necessary?

Comment: @Frugras - Excellent point.  I stand corrected.  For some reason I thought if was returning a string formatted as desired.  Interestingly, doing a `( addZeroes( 1 ) === '1.00' )` comparison returns true, but a `typeof` on the result of `addZeroes` outputs `number`.  You are correct.

Comment: `num.split` is not a function

Comment: @Toskan in this case `num` is actually a string representation of a float so it will work

Comment: up to you if you want to insist or want to add an if. Many people in SOF want to be scrum master instead of actually helping the thousands and thousands of people that land here.  I always updated my answers to help people, even if the answer was, say, about apache, I would include nginx etc. if it was simple. But up to you.

Comment: @Toskan you'll see in my answer I showed how to cast a number to a string and vice versa, so I think I provided enough information to be helpful. Thanks for your input though.

Comment: Oh I see. Well for anyone who is interested in a working snippet: random_user_name's answer works fine here https://stackoverflow.com/a/24039563/533426 and should imho be the accepted answer

Answer (score 44):

Maybe use [**`.toLocaleString()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString):

```
var num = 5.1;    
var numWithZeroes = num.toLocaleString("en",{useGrouping: false,minimumFractionDigits: 2});
console.log(numWithZeroes);
```

As a function/demo:

```js
function addZeroes(num) {
   return num.toLocaleString("en", {useGrouping: false, minimumFractionDigits: 2})
}

console.log('before   after       correct');
console.log('5      ->', addZeroes(5) , '  --> 5.00');
console.log('5.1    ->', addZeroes(5.1) , '  --> 5.10');
console.log('5.11   ->', addZeroes(5.11) , '  --> 5.11 (no change)');
console.log('5.111  ->', addZeroes(5.111) , ' --> 5.111 (no change)');
console.log('5.1111 ->', addZeroes(5.1111) , '--> 5.1111 (no change)');
console.log('-5     ->', addZeroes(-5) , ' --> -5.00');
```

And if you must use `.toFixed()`, here's a one-liner:

```
var num = 5.1;    
var numWithZeroes = num.toFixed(Math.max(((num+'').split(".")[1]||"").length, 2));
console.log(numWithZeroes);
```

Or, again, as a function/demo:

```js
function addZeroes(num) {
   return num.toFixed(Math.max(((num+'').split(".")[1]||"").length, 2));
}

console.log('before   after       correct');
console.log('5      ->', addZeroes(5) , '  --> 5.00');
console.log('5.1    ->', addZeroes(5.1) , '  --> 5.10');
console.log('5.11   ->', addZeroes(5.11) , '  --> 5.11 (no change)');
console.log('5.111  ->', addZeroes(5.111) , ' --> 5.111 (no change)');
console.log('5.1111 ->', addZeroes(5.1111) , '--> 5.1111 (no change)');
console.log('-5     ->', addZeroes(-5) , ' --> -5.00');
```

Answer (score 18):

The below code provides one way to do what you want.  There are others.

```
function addZeroes(num) {
    // Cast as number
    var num = Number(num);
    // If not a number, return 0
    if (isNaN(num)) {
        return 0;
    }
    // If there is no decimal, or the decimal is less than 2 digits, toFixed
    if (String(num).split(".").length < 2 || String(num).split(".")[1].length<=2 ){
        num = num.toFixed(2);
    }
    // Return the number
    return num;
}

console.log(addZeroes(5)); // Alerts 5.00
console.log(addZeroes(5.1)); // Alerts 5.10
console.log(addZeroes(5.11)); // Alerts 5.11
console.log(addZeroes(5.111)); // Alerts 5.111
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nzK4n/

Comment: Would it be possible to remove/leave off the main integer if it's zero?  ie .5 --> .50  rather than the current result, .5 -- 0.50

Comment: @Chase - certainly is possible, but that's a different question than the one being answered here.

Comment: I tried addZeroes(23) and it kept giving me zero, I had to change line 3 to var num = parseInt(num); and isNan to !Number.isInteger(num) for it to work for me.

Comment: Just tested the code again, is working properly.  Interesting you had challenges.  Note that your change to `!Number.isInteger(num)` will cause this to _not work_ for floats (such as `5.1`), because 5.1 is not an integer, it's a float.n

Comment: ` var num` makes no sense as num is already declared in the function argument. So just `num`

Answer (score 11):

```js
decimalNumber = number => Number.isInteger(number) ? number.toFixed(2) : number
```

Comment: solution is good but need to update this conditional operator as decimalNumber = number => Number.isInteger(number) ? number : number.toFixed(2)

Comment: decimalNumber = number => Number.isInteger(number) ? number : number.toFixed(2)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a function that will do this, function expects a number

```
var addZeroes = function(num) {
  var numberAsString = num.toString();

  if(numberAsString.indexOf('.') === -1) {
    num = num.toFixed(2);
    numberAsString = num.toString();
  } else if (numberAsString.split(".")[1].length < 3) {
    num = num.toFixed(2);
    numberAsString = num.toString();
  }

  return numberAsString
};
```

Answer (score 1):

This solution checks if the number is fixed:

```
decimalNumber = number => Number.isInteger(number) && number % 1 === 0 ? number : number.toFixed(4);
```

Answer (score 0):

For number type textbox

Append .00 if number present

```js
function addZeroes(ev) {
    debugger;
    // Convert input string to a number and store as a variable.
    var value = Number(ev.value);
    // Split the input string into two arrays containing integers/decimals
    var res = ev.value.split(".");
    // If there is no decimal point or only one decimal place found.
    if (res.length == 1 || res[1].length < 3) {
        // Set the number to two decimal places
        value = value.toFixed(2);
    }
    // Return updated or original number.
    if (ev.value != "") {
        ev.value = String(value);
    }
}
```

```html
<input type="number" step=".01" onchange="addZeroes(this)" />
```

Comment: Question: I tried adding commas like this (ev.value = String(value).replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");), but after leaving the textbox after entering numbers, if I try to go back in to edit I get NaN, and I'm sure that is due to the commas. How do I work around?

Comment: Cannot edit that for some reason: The replace isn't the issue after all. Happens without it.

Answer (score 0):

For what is worth, this is my recursive solution to this:

```
const addZeros = (decimal, value, check = true) => {
  if (check && decimal <= value.length) return value;
  if (decimal <= 0) return value;
  const newValue = value.length <= decimal ? '0' + value : value;
  return addZeros(decimal - 1, newValue, false);
};
```

- `decimal` is the number of decimal you want
- `value` is the value you want
- `check` is not suppose to be set, it's here to prevent some issue in the first call

e.g:

- `addZeros(3, "3")` -> `003`
- `addZeros(3, "30")` -> `030`
- `addZeros(3, "300")` -> `300`
- `addZeros(3, "3000")` -> `3000`

Answer (score 0):

We can solve this using pipe in angular. we will pass digit information parameter to decimal pipe and see how it works -

Digit Info Parameter (3.2-5):

```
{{ decimal_value | number:'3.2-5' }}
```

In the above code we are instructing decimal pipe to show atleast 3 integer values before decimal points and minimum 2 fraction digit, maximum 5 fraction digits.

```
if decimal_value = 5.123 then it will print 005.12300
if decimal_value = 53.1 then it will print  053.10
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
let a = 12
console.log(a.toLocaleString("en", {useGrouping: false, minimumFractionDigits: 2}))
```

Output: `12.00`