# How to use toFixed properly while entering input value

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'd like to keep the two digits after a number ie `2.89` or `2.00`. Google brought me to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24038971/add-00-tofixed-only-if-number-has-less-than-two-decimal-places) to use `.toFixed(2)`.

While that works great, it does not work well when entered `input` values:

```js
const [ value, setValue] = useState()

const onChange = (value) => {
  const float = parseFloat(value)
  setValue(float.toFixed(2))
}


<input
  type="number"
  value={value}
  onChange={({ target }) => onChange(target.value)}
/>
```

If I should type, say, "300", the input value stops at "3.00". I have to move the cursor before "3" to type "300". What's the best way to do this?

I expect the value to always show `.33`, `.00` etc while having the ability to "free type". As I type this question, I feel I need to use `onBlur` to convert the value to `.toFixed` and not while typing?

Comment: Yep, you are on right track, use `onBlur`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `onBlur` and add some checks in while setting value

```js
export default function App() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState('');
  const onChange = (v) => {
    if (!Number.isNaN(v)) {
      setValue(v);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input
        type="number"
        value={value}
        step="1"
        onChange={({ target }) => onChange(target.value)}
        onBlur={e => setValue(Number(value).toFixed(2))}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Yes, I though there would be a much cleaner way to do this. But hey, it works. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I would not try to set the decimal places on the number on the `onChange` but make an `onBlur` handler.

```
const TodoApp = ( ) => {
  const [ value, setValue] = React.useState('');

  const onBlur = (e) => {
    const float = parseFloat(e.target.value)
    setValue(float.toFixed(2))
  }



  return (
    <input
      type="number"
      value={value}
      onChange={(e) => setValue(e.target.value)}
      onBlur={onBlur}
    />
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi dude read this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/number

And try using step propety, i recommended

```
<input
  type="number"
  value={value}
  step="1"
  onChange={({ target }) => onChange(target.value)}
/>
```

and try if it works

Comment: Thanks for your answer but the correct way was to use `onBlur()`. Try it out ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
export const InputElement = () =>  {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(0);
  const fixInt = (v) => {
    setValue(Number(v).toFixed(2));
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input
        type="number"
        value={value}
        step="1"
        onChange={({ target }) => fixInt(target.value)}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Can you add some description or comment how this code works and why it fixes the problem? It will help further StackOverflow generations to understand the context without decrypting the code.