# jQuery - Allow only two decimal values

Tags: jquery

**Code:**

```
<input onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" type="number" value="" />

function isNumberKey(evt){
    var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode
    if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57) && charCode != 46){   
        return false;
    }   
    return true;
}
```

The above function allows user to enter value with more than two decimal i.e. `10.5678`. How can I modify the function and restrict user to enter values upto two decimal i.e. `10.56`

Comment: Hi! Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9539513/is-there-a-reliable-way-in-javascript-to-obtain-the-number-of-decimal-places-of

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try below code
give class number to element

```
$('.number').on('keypress',function (event) {
    if ((event.which != 46 || $(this).val().indexOf('.') != -1) && (event.which < 48 || event.which > 57)) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
    var input = $(this).val();
    if ((input.indexOf('.') != -1) && (input.substring(input.indexOf('.')).length > 2)) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

and for javascript

```js
function isNumberKey(evt){
  
console.log(evt.value);
  if ((evt.which != 46 || evt.value.indexOf('.') != -1) && (evt.which < 48 || evt.which > 57)) {
        //event it's fine

    }
    var input = evt.value;
    if ((input.indexOf('.') != -1) && (input.substring(input.indexOf('.')).length > 2)) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

```html
<input onkeypress="return isNumberKey(this)" type="number" value="" />
```

Comment: Nirmal:Could you modify your code with the above function ?

Comment: Or if you could modify the `onkeypress` event with our code

Comment: I have updated code, can you have a look on it @Slimshadddyyy

Comment: Nirmal: Check the fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/e0orb0qq/7/
If you press tab, you can not move to next input box. Can that be resolved ?

Comment: Nirmal: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30190474/can-not-edit-delete-input-value#30190474

Comment: Your code is fail on when we put the values through paste.