# jQuery - Can not edit/delete input value in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery

Restricting user to enter values upto two decimal i.e. `10.56` only.

```
<input class="number" type="text" value="" />
<input type="text" value="44" />
```

```js
$('.number').on('keypress',function (event) {
    if ((event.which != 46 || $(this).val().indexOf('.') != -1) && (event.which < 48 || event.which > 57)) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
    var input = $(this).val();
    if ((input.indexOf('.') != -1) && (input.substring(input.indexOf('.')).length > 2)) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

The [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e0orb0qq/7/) works. But if a user press `delte/tab/backspace`, nothing happens.

How to allow user to `edit/delete` input value or move to next input box using `tab` button ?

Answer Reference : [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30187846/jquery-allow-only-two-decimal-values)

Comment: That's because you blocked him to use any key after 2 decimals. Can you add exceptions to your rule?

Comment: If the fiddle works but it doesn't on your site, you most likely are missing the DOMReady handler; `$(function() { /* your code here */ });`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, even in the fiddle, user can not edit value or use tab button

Comment: It's works fine for me here in Chrome on OSX

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, true, but not in FF

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can escape the related keyboards keys. See the [Javascript Char Codes](http://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes), to know the key escaped.

See live demo :

```js
$('.number').on('keypress',function (event) {

  // Add this condition to escape arrow/tab/delete/... and many others keys
  if(event.which <= 46) {
    return true;
  }

  if ((event.which != 46 || $(this).val().indexOf('.') != -1) && (event.which < 48 || event.which > 57)) {
    event.preventDefault();
  }
  var input = $(this).val();
  if ((input.indexOf('.') != -1) && (input.substring(input.indexOf('.')).length > 2)) {
    event.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="number" type="text" value="" />

<input type="text" value="44" />
```

**Update :**

Add in your fiddle an if confition :

```
var acceptedKeys = [9, 37, 39, 46, 8];
if(acceptedKeys.indexOf(charCode) > -1) {
    return true;
}
```

With this code you accept this keys :

- backspace
- delete
- left arrow
- right arrow
- tab

http://jsfiddle.net/e0orb0qq/29/

Comment: R3tep: How can we make it work with this fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/e0orb0qq/22/ using only JS ?

Comment: R3tep: Thanks for the fiddle, but now it allows to enter more than two decimal values which should not

Comment: @Slimshadddyyy http://jsfiddle.net/e0orb0qq/25/ This is my last fiddle. I am not here to develop for you!

Comment: Agree that you are not here to develop for me, but in the fiddle if you delete a value say `10.55`, using delete button, and try to change it to say `8.55`, it does not allow i.e. value before decimal can not be changed